# Excel office xml - get cell's Row and Column numeric index?

Tags: xml, excel, ms-office

In Excel Office XML, the Cell object has the CellReference property which returns a string in the format of "A5", for example.

But is there a good way to get Cell's row and column as NUMERIC values ?
In this example, RowIndex would be 5 and ColumnIndex would be 1.

Yes, they can be parsed from the CellReference, but for large documents (40,000 rows +),
it would be more efficient to deal with numeric values.

Comment: what language and framework are you using to deal with excel?

Comment: C#, Framework 4.0, does it really make a difference ?

Comment: Is there a reason for using openxml? I am amused by why anyone should use openxml considering it is more of working with xml and regex, if not peeking into xml.

Comment: Is there another alternative for creating / reading Office docs on the server side ?  I am using this SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @shahkalpesh was it OpenXML or ExcelXML  ? it is not clear.